# Why does $|(d\exp_{p})_{v}(w)|$ encodes the rate of spreading of geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm reading a discussion in Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry", about Jacobi's equation.
The writer uses the following notation:
$$v(s):I\to T_{p}M\ \ \ s.t. \\
v(0)=v,\\
v'(0)=w
$$ We identify $T_pM\simeq T_vT_p M $.

The writer motivates the discussion by the following claim:

> We would like to obtain information on $|(d\exp_{p})_{v}(w)|$. One of the reasons for this is that $|(d\exp_{p})_{v}(w)|$ denotes, intuitively, the rate of spreading of the geodesics:
> $$ t \to \exp_{p}(t v(s)) 
> $$

I don't understand the heuristic above. To be concrete, I'd like to know:

1. The spread of which geodesics is encoded in $|(d\exp_{p})_{v}(w)|$? Is it some property that relates the following family of geodesics: $$\{t \to \exp_{p}(t v(s)) \}_{s\in I}$$
2. I'd be glad to hear a bit more about that - Why exactly does the differential encodes spread of geodesics? What is the geometric interpretation of all that?
3. Could anyone point me to some draw of figure explaining this heuristic graphically?

It all sort of make sense, but I think some more details could be of tremendous help.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is an attempt to explain the intuition behind Do Carmo's statement.
There will be a lot of abuses of notations, which could be justified on a vector space and therefore, in local coordinates.
For instance, we will perform additions on a manifold and differences between two points whose results are tangent vectors.
I believe too rigorous notations would have resulted in a loss of clarity.

This stunt is performed by a professional.
Don't do this at home.

---

Fix $p\in M$, and consider two vectors $v,v' \in T_pM$.
Let $w=v'-v$.

If $w$ is small (that is, if $v$ an $v'$ are close), then intuitively
$$
\exp_p(v')=\exp_p(v+w) \simeq \exp_p(v) + (d\exp_p)_vw,
$$
(this is the meaning of the derivative of a function) from which one would like to write,
$$
\exp_p(v') - \exp_p(v) \simeq (d\exp_p)_vw.
$$
With a total violation of the concept of rigour, let us write
$$
|\exp_p(v') - \exp_p(v)| \simeq |(d\exp_p)_vw|.
$$
In some more rigorous notations (but that we haven't justified), this means
$$
d_g\left(\exp_p(v+w),\exp_p(v)\right) \simeq \|(d\exp_p)_v(w)\|
$$
when $w$ is small.
See the picture below, where $\gamma_{p,v}(t) = \exp_p(tv)$ and $\gamma_{p,v'}(t) = \exp_p(tv')$.
[image]

If $v(s)$ is a family of tangent vectors in $T_pM$, define $\gamma_s(t) = \exp_p(tv(s))$.
Then $\{\gamma_s\}$ is a family of geodesics passing through $p$ and whose initial data is $\gamma'_s(0)=v(s)$.
See the picture below.
[image]

From the definition of the derivative of a function, one would like to write
$$
\gamma_s(t) \simeq \gamma_0(t) + s\left.\frac{\partial \gamma_s(t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0},
$$
which, from the discussion above, brings us, for small $s$,
$$
d_g\left(\gamma_s(t),\gamma_0(t)\right) \simeq |s| \left\|\left.\frac{\partial \gamma_s(t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0}\right\|.
$$
Hence, $\left.\frac{\partial \gamma_s(t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0}$ encodes how distant are the points $\{\gamma_s(t)\}$, for $t$ fixed and $s$ moving around $0$.
In other word, the vector field $t\mapsto \left.\frac{\partial \gamma_s(t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0}$ along the curve $\gamma_0$ encodes how the different curves $\{\gamma_s\}$ are distant from $\gamma_0$ at first order.

From an easy calculation, we have
$$
\left.\frac{\partial \gamma_s(t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=0} = \left(d\exp_p\right)_{tv(0)}(tv'(0)).
$$
It follows that, on an intuitive level, $\left(d\exp_p\right)_{tv(0)}(tv'(0))$ encodes how distant are the point $\gamma_s(t)$ from $\gamma_0(t)$, for $s$ small.
Do Carmo is considering this at time $t=1$, and
the bigger $\left\|\left(d\exp_p\right)_{v(0)}(v'(0))\right\|$ is, the bigger is the distance between $\exp_p(v)$ and $\exp_p(v(s))$ for small $s$.

The relevant, rigorous and useful concept for studying the rate of spreading of a family of geodesics is the concept of [Jacobi fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field).
I suspect that Do Carmo introduces them just after this discussion.

Comment: This looks like a great intuitive explanation. Can you please clarify what is $(d\exp_p)_vw$? Is it something "acting on" $w$? A vector acting on a vector?

Comment: @JAP $\exp_p$ is a smooth map from $T_pM$ to $M$. Its differential at $v\in T_pM$ is a linear map $(d\exp_p)_v\colon T_v(T_pM= \to T_{\exp_p(v)}M$. It takes a vector $w\in T_v(T_pM)$ to a vector $(d\exp_p)_v(w) \in T_{\exp_p(v)}M$. Since $T_pM$ is a vector space, $T_v(T_pM) \simeq T_pM$ canonically.

Comment: $(d\exp_p)_v\colon T_v(T_pM) \to T_{\exp_p(v)}M$, sorry. The keys `=` and `)` are next to each other on my keyboard

Comment: @Didier I'm having a hard time convincing myself with this explanation. $$
\exp_p(v')=\exp_p(v+w) \simeq \exp_p(v) + ({ \rm d} \exp_p)_vw,
$$ doesn't really make any sense, since $\exp_p(v')$ and $ \exp_p(v)$ are points of $M$ (which is a priori not a vector space) while $ ({\rm d}\exp_p)_v w$ is a tangent vector at the point $\exp_p(v)$. I think your arguments would make a lot more sense if you applied them to the coordinate representations of the functions $\exp$ and ${\rm d} \exp$ (since you'll be bringing everything to an actual vector space).

Comment: That being said, pretty good answer!

Comment: @MatheusAndrade You're right, it does not make sense on a manifold, only on vector spaces. That's why I started by saying "forget about rigour" and "total violation of the concept of rigour". Maybe I should make this even more explicit!

Comment: @Didier Sorry if my tone seemed hostile, that was not my intention, your answer was pretty good. I only added my comment because I think you could make it a tiny bit more rigorous if you applied your heuristics to the coordinate representation of the functions, which indeed have images in vector spaces.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Hope this is better now! (Edit: no worry, your tone was okay and I didn't think it was hostile!)

Comment: @Didier it is indeed! Thanks! :)